# Are there any implementations of slashdot style moderation in python?

Tags: python

Are there any implementations of slashdot style moderation in python?

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific about what "slashdot style moderation" means to you.  Because to me, that phrase often translates to "the blind leading the stupid", and that's hard to express in python.

Answer (score 1):

On slash ports site (http://www.slashcode.com/slashalikes.shtml) a Python version isn't listed. You may try to use slash perl code as a guide and develop your own version, though.